# How To Reload The Web Page Using A Button In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-api, fetch-api

i'm presently working on a gitHub battle game with JavaScript manipulations. Please, how can i make the "PLAY AGAIN" button restart the game. (Starting All Over Again)

I also want to make the "DIV WITH CONTROL-BUTTON ID" display as block only if data fetch from API was successful.... Thanks

MY CODE IS BELOW:

```js
"use strict";
let user = document.getElementsByClassName('github-username'),
  player1 = document.getElementById('player-one'),
  player2 = document.getElementById('player-two'),
  form1 = document.getElementById('form1'),
  form2 = document.getElementById('form2'),
  cont1 = document.getElementById('continue1'),
  cont2 = document.getElementById('continue2'),
  reSelect = document.getElementById('reselect-players'),
  playAgain = document.getElementById('play-again'),
  initiate = document.getElementById('initiate-battle');

// Function that activate the start button
function getStarted() {
  let startPage = document.getElementById('startPage'),
    startBtn = document.getElementById('get-started-button');
  startBtn.onclick = function() {
    startPage.style.display = "none";
    player1.style.display = "block";
  };
};
getStarted();

// Function that initiates player 1 input
function firstForm() {
  player1.style.display = "none";
  player2.style.display = "block";
  return false;
};

// Function that initiates player 2 input
function secondForm() {
  let confirmPage = document.getElementById('confirm-page');
  player2.style.display = "none";
  confirmPage.style.display = "block";

  // Function that fetches users data from input
  function fetchUsers() {
    let user1, user2;
    fetch("https://api.github.com/users/" + user[0].value)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        // Log the data to the console
        console.log(data);
        // Cache the data to a variable
        user1 = data;
        let myUser1 = document.getElementById('user1-container'),
          totalScore = (1 * user1.followers + 1 * user1.following + 0.5 * user1.public_repos);
        myUser1.innerHTML = `<ul class="user-info">
<p id="firstPlayer"> Player 1 </p>
<li id="score">Score: <span class="totalScr"> ${totalScore}</span> </li>
<li><img class="avatar" src="${user1.avatar_url}"></li>
<li>Name: ${user1.name} </li>
<li>Username: ${user1.login} </li>
<li>Following: ${user1.following} </li>
<li>Followers: ${user1.followers} </li>
<li>Repository: ${user1.public_repos} </li>
</ul>`;
        //Make another API call and pass it into the stream
        return fetch("https://api.github.com/users/" + user[1].value)
          .then(function(response) {
            //Get a JSON object from the response
            return response.json();
          })
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        //Log the data to the console
        console.log(data);
        // Cache the data to a variable
        user2 = data;
        //Now that you have both APIs back, you can do something with the data
        let myUser2 = document.getElementById('user2-container'),
          totalScore2 = (1 * user2.followers + 1 * user2.following + 0.5 * user2.public_repos);
        myUser2.innerHTML = `<ul class="user-info">
<p id="secondPlayer"> Player 2 </p>
<li id="score2">Score: <span class="totalScr"> ${totalScore2}</span> </li>
<li><img class="avatar" src="${user2.avatar_url}"></li>
<li>Name: ${user2.name} </li>
<li>Username: ${user2.login} </li>
<li>Following: ${user2.following} </li>
<li>Followers: ${user2.followers} </li>
<li>Repository: ${user2.public_repos} </li>
</ul>`;
      })
  };

  fetchUsers();
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('control-buttons').style.display = "block";
    playAgain.style.display = "none";
  }, 1500);
  return false;
};
//Function that assign users score and winner
initiate.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("confirm-players").innerHTML = "Winner";
  document.getElementById('score').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('score2').style.display = "block";
  initiate.style.display = "none";
  reSelect.style.display = "none";
  playAgain.style.display = "block";

  let totalScr = document.getElementsByClassName("totalScr"),
    totalScr1 = parseFloat(totalScr[0].innerText),
    totalScr2 = parseFloat(totalScr[1].innerText);

  if (totalScr1 > totalScr2) {
    document.getElementById("firstPlayer").innerHTML = "Winner";
    document.getElementById("secondPlayer").innerHTML = "Loser";
  } else if (totalScr1 < totalScr2) {
    document.getElementById("firstPlayer").innerHTML = "Loser";
    document.getElementById("secondPlayer").innerHTML = "Winner";
  } else {
    confirm("IT'S A TIE, PLAY AGAIN");
  };
};

reSelect.onclick = function() {
  confirmPage.style.display = "none";
  player1.style.display = "block";
  user[0].value = null;
  user[1].value = null;
};

playAgain.onclick = function() {
  //Make this function start the game again, following the usual pattern
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, cursive;
  background-image: url('images/photo.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input[type=text] {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 50px 0 15px;
}

.body-container {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.body-container p {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.head-text {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

#confirm-players {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0 5px;
}

#get-started-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 10%;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white
}

.continue-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  border: none;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white
}

#get-started-button:hover,
.continue-button:hover,
#initiate-battle:hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.github-username {
  width: 65%;
  height: 35px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 0 15px;
}

#score,
#score2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#player-one,
#player-two {
  display: none;
}

#confirm-page,
#winner {
  display: none;
  margin: 20px 0 10px;
}

#initiate-battle,
#play-again {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin: 15px auto 5px;
}

#reselect-players {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.4px;
  width: 240px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

#control-buttons {
  display: none;
}

#reselect-players:hover {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
}

.avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.myUsers {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
}

ul {
  margin-left: -30px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#firstPlayer,
#secondPlayer {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="githstyle.css" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="startPage" class="body-container">
      <h1 class="head-text">GitHub Challenge</h1>
      <p>Some challenges are worth engaging </p>
      <button id="get-started-button">Get Started</button>
    </div>

    <div id="player-one" class="body-container">
      <h1 class="head-text">Player One</h1>
      <div class="form-container">
        <form id="form1" onsubmit="return firstForm();">
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="github-username" placeholder="Enter Player's GitHub Username" required>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Continue" id="continue1" class="continue-button">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="player-two" class="body-container">
      <h1 class="head-text">Player Two</h1>
      <div class="form-container">
        <form id="form2" onsubmit="return secondForm()">
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="" class="github-username" placeholder="GitHub Username" required>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Continue" id="continue1" class="continue-button">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="confirm-page" class="body-container">
      <h1 id="confirm-players">Confirm players</h1>
      <div id="user1-container" class="myUsers">
      </div>
      <div id="user2-container" class="myUsers">
      </div>

      <div id="control-buttons">
        <div>
          <button id="initiate-battle">Initiate Battle</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="reselect-players">Reselect Players</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button id="play-again">Play Again</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="gith.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Use `location.reload();`

Comment: thank you a bunch, but kindly look into the line of codes for any error or correction. Thank you

Comment: @AhmadHabib it really worked

Comment: Glad to help. Readout more from https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading the page using JavaScript is very easy.

You can achieve this by using `location.reload()`

If you want to achieve reloading using a `button`, then be sure to add a  `return false;` right after you call `location.reload()` to prevent bubbling (parents of the button won't know the event occurred).

So, your code will look something like this :

```
document.getElementById('yourButton').addEventListener('click', function(){

        location.reload();
        return false;

    });
```

Hope this helps ! :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I worked perfectly 